# Read files in a directory starting by a specific date using python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have an automated process and  need to perform some operations with files. Another process creates these files and stores them in a directory, I only need to work with recent files but have to leave these files in there and never delete them, because of the amount of files I think the process is starting to use a lot of resources when I get the files needed.

My initial idea was to create another process that copies the most recent files(with an extra day just to be sure) to another folder but I just wondering(or I'm sure hehe) if there's a better way to get these files without reading all of them or if my code can be optimized.

My main issue is that when I get to this part of the code, the CPU usage of the server is getting of the charts and I assume that at some point the process will just break due to some OS error. I just need to get the names of the files needed, which are the ones where the creation date is greater than the last file I used, Every time I perform an operation on a file the name goes to a table in a DB which is where I get the name of the last file. My issue isn't with the queries or the operations performed, the CPU usage it's minimum, just this part where I read all the files and compare the dates of them and add them to an array.

Here's my code(don't get to angry if it's horrendous) the heavy load starts after the for:

```
def get_ordered_files():
    valid_files = []
    epoch = datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(0)
    get_last_file = check_last_successful_file()
    last_date = os.path.getctime(get_last_file)
    files = glob.glob(files_location + file_extension)
    files.sort(key=os.path.getctime, reverse=False)
    for single_file in files:
        total_days_file = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getctime(single_file)) - epoch
        total_days_last = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(last_date) - epoch
        if total_days_file.total_seconds() > total_days_last.total_seconds():
            check_empty = get_email_account(single_file)
            if check_empty != "" and check_empty is not None:
                valid_files.append(single_file)
    return valid_files
```

Thank you very much for all your help(I'm using python 3.8).

Comment: People won't get angry over your code, but you may get some feedback on your question - it's not clear what 'operations' you plan to perform on these files. Do you intend to change the files? Is it OK if that changes their file date (so they might get picked up again)? How many files are we talking about and how often does this need to run?

Comment: Thanks @Grismar, I added more info to my question. The files stay the same the operations are done in just by reading them.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of redundant operations going on in your code.

For example, the use of `fromtimestamp()` to calculate `total_days_last` inside the loop can simply be done once outside of the loop. In fact, the use of `datetime` functions and mucking about with `epoch` seems unnecessary because you can simply compare the file `ctime` values directly.

`os.path.getctime()` is called twice on every file: once for the sort and a second time to calculate `total_days_file`.

These repetitive calculations over a large number of files would be part of the performance problem.

Another issue is that, if there are a large number of files, the list `files` could become very large and require a lot of memory.

`if check_empty != "" and check_empty is not None:` can simply be written as `if check_empty:`

Here is a simplified version:

```
def get_ordered_files():
    last_ctime = os.path.getctime(check_last_successful_file())
    files = glob.glob(files_location + file_extension)
    files.sort(key=os.path.getctime)
    return [f for f in files
                if os.path.getctime(f) > last_ctime and get_email_account(f)]
```

This eliminates most of the redundant code but still calls `os.path.getctime()` twice for each file. To avoid that we can store the `ctime` for each file on the first occasion it is obtained.

```
pattern = os.path.join(files_location, file_extension)

def get_ordered_files():
    last_ctime = os.path.getctime(check_last_successful_file())
    files = ((filename, ctime) for filename in glob.iglob(pattern)
                if (ctime := os.path.getctime(filename)) > last_ctime and
                    get_email_account(filename))
    return (filename for filename, _ in sorted(files, key=itemgetter(1)))
```

Here a generator expression is assigned to `files`. It uses [`glob.iglob()`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/glob.html#glob.iglob) which is an iterator version of `glob.glob()` that does not store all the files at once. Both the file name and its ctime value are stored as tuples. The generator expression filters out files that are too old and files that don't have an associated email account. Finally another generator is returned that sorts the files by ctime. The calling code can then iterate over the generator, or call `list()` on it to realise it as a list.