# Program to check all last modified files in a folder using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-2.7, pycharm

```
import glob
import os
import time
Path = 'Aabmatica/*'#Folder path
list_of_files = glob.glob(Path) # * Name of the folder in which all files exist
latest_file = max(list_of_files, key=os.path.getmtime)
print()
print("last modified/added file is:",end=" ")
print(latest_file)
print()
modification_time = os.path.getmtime(latest_file)
local_time = time.ctime(modification_time)
print("modified time: ",local_time)
```

2. I made a python program which gives me name of last modified file in a folder:-
3. This program is running well but the problem is that if I place new file or if I am editing any file in a folder than it is giving me correct output but if I am copying any file into the folder than I am not getting any output.
4. And how can I show all the last modified files from folder using this program.

5.So there is basically two problem with this program if I am copying any file into folder than I am not getting the file name and I am unable to show all the last modified files from folder.

Comment: Which OS? I am finding that your code works on Linux.

Comment: I am using windows and this code is working  when I am creating/editing new file in a folder but if I am copying any file into the folder then it's not showing the file name as recently added file or copied file.

Comment: Also, `max()` will pick the latest file according to the sort key, but if there are equal keys it will pick the file with the greatest alphabetical name.

Comment: actually it is working sir whatever the keys are but the thing is that if I cut-paste any file or copy any file in to the folder then my code is not showing this copied file but if I make a new file or edit existing file in a folder then it is showing me the correct answer, what I want is whatever is the new change in a folder then it must show the change

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Windows a copy of a file probably has a new creation time. You can look at [`os.path.getctime()`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/os.path.html#os.path.getctime) to check the creation time for the copy of the file.

If that works as expected then you could include `os.path.getctime()` as an additional check in the key to `max()`.

```
def latest_change(filename):
    return max(os.path.getmtime(filename), os.path.getctime(filename))

latest_file = max(list_of_files, key=latest_change)
```

The key function just grabs whichever of the modification or creation time is greatest, and then uses that greatest time as the key.

Comment: ok sir let me try it but what if I want to show all modification within 30 minutes ???

Comment: You mean to show all files that have been modified in the last 30 minutes?Take tje current time less 30 minutes as a reference time, and find all files with either ctime or mtime greater than the reference time.

Comment: yes sir your code is working even my pasted code is also working as you said above

Comment: SIr I am unable to make this condition work

Comment: Your original question has been answered. If you are happy with that then you might upvote this answer and mark it accepted please. Regarding the 30 min condition, check this recent similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65711707/read-files-in-a-directory-starting-by-a-specific-date-using-python. Ask a new question if that doesn't help you.

Comment: Glad to hear that. You might consider upvoting my answer and marking it as accepted.